# Reading and printing values in a file

Tags: c++, ifstream, eof

I am trying to read a file and then print it but the loop doesn't ends. Why??

My file contains one line such as

```
    66,67,256,258,69,73,
```

This is my input :

```
char d;
char code2 [12]={0};
string file1;
cout<<"Input file name"<<endl;
cin>>file1;
string file2;
cout<<"Input file name"<<endl;
cin>>file2;

ifstream input;
input.open(file1.c_str());
ofstream output;
output.open(file2.c_str());

while(! input.eof())
    {
        int i=0;
        while(d != ',' && i < sizeof(code2))
        {
            input>>d;
            code2[i]=d;
            i++;
        }
        file2<<code2;
    }
```

While debugging, I am getting a garbage value of code2. Thus, the loop doesn't ends at end of while.

Comment: Don't use `eof`. There are countless questions and answers on SO about this very topic. Search.

Comment: Read _[Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/1870232)_

Comment: Consider what happens when `d == ','` starting from the top of the nested loop (hint: how is `input` supposed to reach eof?).

Comment: Try sprinkling print statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `eof()` is wrong, and you are using `d` before initializing it.  Try something more like this instead:

```
char d;
char code2 [13]={0};
string file1;
cout<<"Input file name"<<endl;
cin>>file1;
string file2;
cout<<"Input file name"<<endl;
cin>>file2;

ifstream input;
input.open(file1.c_str());
ofstream output;
output.open(file2.c_str());

int i = 0;
while(input >> d)
    {
    if ((d == ',') || (i == 12))
        {
        code2[i] = 0;
        file2<<code2;
        i = 0;
        }
    code2[i] = d;
    i++;
    }

if (i > 0)
    {
    code2[i] = 0;
    file2<<code2;
    }
```